# Objective C Checking for alphanumeric characters is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code to check if my string contains any non-alphanumeric characters:

```
NSString *initials = @"Å漢";
NSCharacterSet *unwantedCharacters = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
// See if we can find any of the unwanted characters
return [initials rangeOfCharacterFromSet:unwantedCharacters].location == NSNotFound;
```

The code is returning true. Why is it not able to find the invalid characters Å and 漢?

Comment: Both of those characters are alphanumeric characters. Why do you think otherwise? What characters are you thinking of when you want just "alphanumeric" characters?

Comment: I can understand if Å is classified as an alphanumeric character. However, what alphabet is 漢 part of? When I think of alphanumeric I think of "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

Comment: If those are the characters you want, make an `NSCharacterSet` using `+characterSetWithCharactersInString:`.

Comment: The `漢` appears to be the word "Chinese" in the Chinese language (according to Google Translate). You are looking for ASCII letters and numbers which is a tiny subset of Unicode letters and numbers.

Comment: Ok I used a characterSetWithCharactersInString instead. Thanks. I am a bit confused though since Chinese is not an alphabetic language, I thought alphanumeric meant letters and numbers. Chinese does not have letters only characters. By the way 漢 is the traditional Chinese character for Han as in the Han people or the Han language :)

Comment: Yeah, the included characters are all based on the Unicode standard and their definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `alphanumericCharacterSet`:

> Informally, this set is the set of all characters used as basic units of alphabets, syllabaries, ideographs, and digits.

The two characters you posted are in fact alphanumeric characters. Based on your comments you want to limit it to ASCII letters and numbers which is a tiny subset of Unicode letters and numbers. Simply do:

```
NSCharacterSet *lettersAndNumbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"];
NSCharacterSet *unwantedCharacters = [lettersAndNumbers invertedSet];
```

Answer (score -1):

NSNotFound is defined to be NSIntegerMax, which on a 64 bit system will be 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Makes sense, so why is it returning NSNotFound despite the input having invalid chars?